# Splatting Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal was incomplete?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute this script using Splatting for the remote server (through PowerShell ISE).

However, it is always stuck and failed.

I've followed the suggestion as in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKMKU/com.ibm.wincollect.doc/t_ug_wincollect_cli_install.html

Script:

```
$Args = @{
    'EXE'='\\PRDFS01-VM\DSL\wincollect-7.3.0-24.x64.exe'
    'INSTALLDIR'='C:\Program Files\IBM\WinCollect\'
    'LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_ENABLED'='True'
    'LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_PARAMETERS'=""
    'Component1.AgentDevice'='DeviceWindowsLog'
    'Component1.Action'='create'
    'Component1.LogSourceName'="$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    'Component1.LogSourceIdentifier'="$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    'Component1.Dest.Name'='IBMQradar'
    'Component1.Dest.Hostname'='192.168.111.111'
    'Component1.Dest.Port'='514'
    'Component1.Dest.Protocol'='TCP'
    'Component1.Log.Security'='true'
    'Component1.Log.System'='true'
    'Component1.Log.Application'='true'
    'Component1.Log.DNS+Server'='true'
    'Component1.Log.File+Replication+Service'='true'
    'Component1.Log.Directory+Service'='true'
    'Component1.RemoteMachinePollInterval'='3000'
    'Component1.EventRateTuningProfile'='Default+(Endpoint)'
    'Component1.MinLogsToProcessPerPass'='100'
    'Component1.MaxLogsToProcessPerPass'='150'
}
$process = Start-Process -ArgumentList "/s" "/v" "/qn" @Args -Wait -PassThru
$process.ExitCode
```

Error:

```
At line:9 char:15
+     Component1.Action=create
+               ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:29 char:18
+ $process.ExitCode
+                  ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:29 char:18
+ $process.ExitCode
+                  ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

OK, after updating it as above, now the error is different:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/qn'.
At line:25 char:12
+ $process = Start-Process -ArgumentList "/s" "/v" "/qn" @Args -Wait -P ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Ignoring the splatting for a minute, PowerShell is treating the ```"/s" "/v" "/qn"``` as positional arguments to ```Start-Process``` (sort of like ```-ArgumentList "/s" -MyPositionalParameter1 "/v" -MyPositionalParameter2 "/qn"```). If you want them to be treated as a list of command line switches you need to comma-separate the items so it represents an array - i.e. ```-ArgumentList "/s", "/v", "/qn"```, or ```-ArgumentList @("/s", "/v", "/qn")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashtable keys cannot contain dots unless you quote them.

This doesn't work.

```
$Args = @{
    EXE='\\PRDFS01-VM\DSL\wincollect-7.3.0-24.x64.exe /s /v"/qn'
    Component1.Action=create
}
```

This does (note that `create` also requires quotes)

```
$Args = @{
    EXE='\\PRDFS01-VM\DSL\wincollect-7.3.0-24.x64.exe /s /v"/qn'
    'Component1.Action'='create'
}
```

ISE will actually even give you syntax errors about this, so I'm not quite sure how that went unnoticed.

Comment: Is the double or single quote different on the hashtable?

Comment: That's not related to hashtables at all. Single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are different in PowerShell (you can look up the difference). In this particular case it doesn't matter.